# LESS CSS Engine import-once duplicate styles

Tags: css, import, less

LESS is importing the same LESS across different files despite using import-once.

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="app.less">
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="theme.less">
```

app.less

```
@import-once "1.less";

body{
    color:blue;
}
```

theme.less

```
@import-once "1.less";

body{
    color:pink;
}
```

produces:

```
<style type="text/css" id="less:good-docs-less-app">
    body {
        background: yellow;
    }
    body {
        color: blue;
    }
</style>

<style type="text/css" id="less:good-docs-less-theme">
    body {
        background: yellow;
    }
    body {
        color: pink;
    }
</style>
```

You notice `body{background:yellow}` is duplicated in both styles.  Is it possible to import this in both LESS files without it writing it twice?

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know. But I would recommend to compile all LESS code into a single file. Doing so, you also reduces the number of calls to the server by one, i.e., a small optimization of speed for your page.

In the projects I am involved, we tend to have a single master file for all LESS and thus, all styles are compiled into a single CSS file.

Example:

- styles.less is the master file. It does not define any styles on its own, but only contains import statements
- variables.less contains some general varialbes that are used all over the project. They are defined once, and reused everywhere. Examples: colors, fonts, headings, etc.
- some more files containing the actual styles. Whenever possible, use LESS mixins to avoid code duplications.

On the other hand, duplicate style defintions are not really severe. Just take care of the order of the CSS style defintions because they overwrite each others.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding what `import-once` does. It prevents the import from occurring again *as the code is compiling **within that .less code***. But your `theme.less` has no "knowledge" of your `app.less` being called prior to it at the time that you are linking them into your `<html>`. By then, `app.less` has already done its work and produced your first section of css.

So the `import-once` only prevents a second import from occurring *within* a particular `.less` file. For instance, if your `app.less` had this:

```
@import-once "1.less";
@import "theme.less";

body{
    color:blue;
}
```

Then the `1.less` file in `theme.less` would not be re-imported because it already was imported once within the `app.less`. At this point, we are sill *inside* LESS code during compiling. That is not the case with two consecutive `<link>` commands inside the `<html>`.

As phammer said in his post, the solution is to compile all the LESS into a single master CSS file to link to the html. This way, you do keep all the LESS code "together" (so it will recognize the `import-once` as you expect).